# Long site names don't look right in dropdown (cause action links to overflow)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

Something doesn't look quite right here:

> [image]

I want to read it as one of these option:

- > Geographic Information - help - chat - log / Systems - out
- > Geographic Information Systems - help out - chat - log

But neither is quite right...

This happens on all sites with really long names:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

(That last one looks especially hard to read, but I'm not sure if that's only because I can't read Japanese or not.)

---

In other words, the bug is that when a site has a long name, it creates a [Don't Dead Open Inside](https://www.reddit.com/r/dontdeadopeninside/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you                                                                        then you don't
   don't love                                                                 deserve
   me at my                                                                 me at my

[image: screenshot of the site switcher without CSS applied]  
[image: screenshot of the site switcher with CSS applied and the bug fixed]

<sub>(fixed in the next build, thanks)</sub>

Comment: Confirmed, but I think a new bug might have been born... the site icons in "More communities" list are now aligned to the top, and think they used to be aligned to the middle before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDcY1.png